# Couchbase Python SDK - How to enforce a custom couchbase connection timeout?

Tags: python, couchbase, connection-timeout

I have the following code for connecting to an existing Couchbase bucket and retrieving a document. How can I enforce a custom timeout value (in seconds) for the couchbase connections?

```
import couchbase
from couchbase.bucket import Bucket
import couchbase.exceptions

cb_nodes="123.456.7.89"
cb_bucket = "default"

def fetch_doc(self, key):
    try: 
         cb = Bucket('couchbase://' + cb_nodes + '/' + cb_bucket)
         doc = cb.get(key)
         return doc
    except couchbase.exceptions.NotFoundError as e:
         print("Key Not Found")
    except couchbase.exceptions.TimeoutError as e:
         print("Couchbase connection timed out")
    except couchbase.exceptions.CouchbaseNetworkError as e:
         print("Couchbase Connection failed")
```

I am using Python 3, Couchbase 4.1 and Python SDK 2.1 for Couchbase.

I found this - https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/developer-guide/error-handling.html#concept_ybj_tqs_zs__devguide-transient-errors but it does not really state how or where I should set a timeout value.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Various settings including timeouts are covered in the [current Client Settings section of the Couchbase Documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/python/client-settings.html).  The link you're referring to is quite a bit older.